# How to detect new posts

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

Using the facebook c# sdk I am able to read my feed data as follows

```
                    var fb = new Facebook.FacebookClient(longlifeaccess_token);
                    dynamic fbFeed = fb.Get("me/feed");
```

However, I need to only be able to detect new posts.  How can I achieve this.?

Does the SDK the feed to be read between two datetimes?

Is there a way to set up a callback so that the SDK notifies my code when a new post is made?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can setup such a callback, but you can iterate through the feed and extract posts until you encounter a previous post. You can detect this by saving the last saved post Id. Below is a shortened snippet of code that does that.

```
  foreach (var item in data)
  {
      var post = (IDictionary<string, object>)item;

      if (post["id"].ToString() == latestPostId)
      {
           end = true;
           break;                               
      }

      //App logic continues...

  }
```

Alternatively, you can use the "since" and "until" parameter, like so: "me/feed?until=10/01/2013" , which would give you the posts before 10/01/2013

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  In the longer run though, how does one avoid having to reread all posts just to have to discard all read ones, in search for the newest, everytime a poll is done on the feed. Is there a way of filtering the feed by date ?